# Create dynamic list with freemarker

Tags: java, freemarker

I want to build a dynmic list with freemarker. Before the (java) run, i don't know how many levels there will be.
It should looks like

```
<ul>
  <li>....</li>
  <li>....</li>
  <ul>
    <li>...</li>
  </ul>
</ul>
```

How could i do that? I'm just getting a static list with x levels... with dirty nested loops, but sometimes i need 20-25 nested `ul` elements / levels.

How can i do that dynamically? Advice would be nice :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is quite easy to do with freemarker, think of how you would do it in Java - with recursion. In this case you should consider each template a function, which has parameters you can use.

Create a new template that just handles one level of the list, and then if another list is present, call the render function again on this template.

Alternatively you can use macros, although this was my personal preference.

Comment: I would prefer macros over templates here, because macros can have local variables (the macro arguments already are, plus you can use `#local` inside macros), which is essential for recursion.

Answer (score 0):

Use a [macro](http://freemarker.org/docs/ref_directive_macro.html) with recursive invocation.

Comment: The answer without the link, while terse, is complete and could be useful (I'm hedging because I don't know freemarker).